# RegExp replacing is causing false result while replacing again

Tags: javascript, regex, string

**My String** : `"<p>Stacked"`
I want to replace it to "<font color=' blue'><</font>p<font color='blue'>></font>Stacked

So I have used this : ⬇

```
var rox = /([<])([a-z1-9]+)([>])/;


function testInfo(phoneInput){ 
    var startTag = "<font color='blue'>";
    var endTag = "</font>";
    var OK = phoneInput.value.replace(rox, function(x){
        var lt = x.replace(/([<])/, startTag+'&lt;'+endTag);
        var gt = lt.replace(/([>])/ , startTag+'&gt;'+endTag);
        return gt;
    });
```

It returns like this

```
<font color='blue'<font color='blue'>p<font color='blue'>&gt;</font>
```

It means when I am replacing the 

Stack

 First time it is replacing to

```
 **<font color='blue'>&lt;</font>p<font color='blue'>&gt;</font>** But next time it is replacing the **">"** of the *font tag*. Lot *">"* of **p tag**.
```

Problem

---

How can I fix it? I am trying something to color/highlight code.

Comment: Whats your input string and whats your desired output string?

Comment: What are the double angle brackets (`<<` and `>>`) in your example output for? Is that a typo or what you actually want?

Comment: `<font color=' blue'><</font>` is not valid HTML. Bare `<` are not allowed and so must always be escaped, i.e. `&lt;`

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2487517) it may cause you to reconsider your approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```js
str = `<p>Stacked`;
const subst1 = `LT_LTfont color=' blue'GT_GT&lt;`;
const subst2 = `LT_LTfont color=' blue'GT_GT&gt;`;
str = str.replace(/</g, subst1);
str = str.replace(/>/g, subst2);

str = str.replace(/GT_GT/g,`>`);
str = str.replace(/LT_LT/g,`<`);

$("#kk").html(str);
console.log(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="kk">

</div>
```

Comment: What is LT_LT and GT_GT here? Are they the other way of &lt; and &gt;

Comment: naah !!! those are used as temporary replacement. You may use something which is unlikely to be a syntax or word. You need to use something in place of < and > temporarily. When you apply the first replacement you again get some < in <font > so that > sign is again going to be replaced by your initial replacement. That is why your were having false result. So you need to use some thing LT_LT GT_GT are temporary thing

Comment: Ow I have got it. Thanks for this awesome idea.